# Exhaustive list of links for a specific domain

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, hyperlink

I have a function that parses the content of a given URL (usually the root of a domain) and returns a list of all links which point somewhere else within that domain –it doesn't include external links and it doesn't allow repeated links.

What would be the most simple way to run that function for each of the links that are already in the list, and then for each of the links that will be found in the next level, and so on, again and again, no matter how deep, no matter how long it takes, until an exhaustive, complete list of links for that specific domain is created?

The method should be reasonably efficient, and it should not use any libraries or modules, and not even list comprehensions. Just basic instructions in the most obvious and explicit way. Also, it's not important to know the structure of the tree. Just a list of links.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49717006/edit) your post to include a language tag, and include your existing attempts to build the function you're describing. (It sounds like the algorithm you want is [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) though).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. Post edited with language tag. I don't have any code yet. I'm a beginner and I'm trying to figure out how to build this in conjunction with the parsing function that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple algorithm to do that

```
links_to_crawl = set()
crawled_links = set()

def function crawl(link):
    if (link not in crawled_links):
        new_links = findAllLinks (link)
        for new_link in new_links:
        #if new_link is not external:
            links_to_crawl.add(new_link)
        crawled_links.add(link)

for (link in links_to_crawl):
    crawl(link)

for (link in crawled_links):
    print crawled_links
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. How can I make this work in combination with my existing function, which parses the page contents? My function doesn't take any argument, if that's relevant. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: This is my code:  

    url = urllib.request.urlopen('python.org')  
    bytes = url.read()  
    
    def scrap():  
    
        list_of_links = []  
        <convert bytes to a character list and manipulate them>  
        <some confusing parsing stuff here>   
     
    return list_of_links  
  
How can I integrate this with your example so that the search becomes exhaustive?